# Use $.post to append to html before adding an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$.post` to get an html page. I then need to take this `data` and append it to the current DOM. However, I need to modify the attributes first, before appending:

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$.post(link, function (data) {
    $(data).css('display', 'none');
    $('#page').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Swap your append around to instead use .appendTo, and do it in 1 line. The problem is you converted data to dom elements twice.

Comment: `data` should be the part of DOM in order to operate on it.. So first make it part of DOM then do operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a string value, when you use `$(data)` it returns a jQuery object for the given markup but the changes made in the jQuery object will not get reflected in the string referred by `data`. So when you use `data` again in the `append()` operation the changes done before is lost.

As a solution you can store the reference to the jQuery object reference you created in the first step and then use that reference in the `append()` operation.

```
$.post(link, function (data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    if (somecondition) {
        $data.css('display', 'none');
    }
    $('#page').append($data);
});
```

Comment: Other way round cant we just make it part of DOM then operate on it?

Comment: @Pilot still you need to get a reference to the newly added element